# how create separate model , view and controller using backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

- I edit my code again and I got the following 2 error :

1) Complex_collection is not defined

```
  model: Complex_model
```

2) Complex_model is not defined

```
 model: Complex_model
```

I am using backbone js following is my code and I done this by using backbone.js but my code is not running I want separate model , view and controller using backbone js

//model

```
(function(){ var Complex_model = Backbone.Model.extend({        
    sync:function() {},
    validate:function() {},
    url:function() {},          
    defaults :{
        name : null
    }    
});})(this);
```

//view

```
(function(){

FriendView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events :{
        'click #add-input' : 'add'
    },
    initialize: function(){
        this.collection = new Complex_collection(); // This is collection
        _.bindAll(this, 'render');
    },      
    add : function() {
        alert("hello");
        var friend_name = $('#input').val();
        this.collection.add({ name : friend_name });
    },
    render : function(){
        $("#friends-list").append("<li>"+ model.get("name")+"</li>");
    },      
});

var view = new FriendView(); })(this);
```

//collection

```
(function(){    

    var Complex_collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    model: Complex_model

});})(this);
```

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not create new instance of the same object in the initialize code, your code should look something like this :

```
(function(){ 
    this.complex_model = Backbone.Model.extend({        
        sync:function() {},
        validate:function() {},
        url:function() {},      
    });
})(this);

// View

(function(){
    var vw = view = function(){};
    FriendView = Backbone.View.extend({
        events :{
            'click #add-input' : 'add'
        },
        initialize: function(){
            this.friendslist = new FriendList(); // This is your collection right?
            _.bindAll(this, 'render');
        },      
        add : function() {
            var friend_name = $('#input').val();
            this.friendslist.add({ name : friend_name });
        },
        render : function(){
            $("#friends-list").append("<li>"+ model.get("name")+"</li>");
        },      
    });
})(this);

// Collection
(function(){    this.complex_collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model : complex_model
});})(this);

// Your main app
var view = new FriendView();
```

Comment: thanks for answering my question i again paste my code and I got 2 errors

Comment: Oh I thought you are using requirejs or some stuff, just remove the wrapping `function()` then and insert `var view = new FriendView();` in your `$(function() { })` wrapper .. look here [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gz33w/)

Comment: thanks a lot !!! actually my question is that i want separate model, view and collection in separate js file . foe example we create in web application separate model ,view and controller

Comment: Just separate the code from the fiddle in different files and load them in your `<script>` tag. This will populate the global variable and is only for experimenting. If you wan't async / module loading you should use requirejs.